# How to count the total in array from within a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array which comes from a report.

This report has info similar to:

```
157479877294,OBSOLETE_ORDER,obelisk,19/01/2013 01:42pm
191532426695,WRONG_PERFORMANCE,g3t1,19/01/2013 01:56pm
159523681637,WRONG_PERFORMANCE,g3t1,19/01/2013 01:57pm
176481653889,WRONG_PERFORMANCE,g4t1,19/01/2013 01:57pm
167479810401,WRONG_PERFORMANCE,g4t1,19/01/2013 02:00pm
172485359309,WRONG_PERFORMANCE,g4t2,19/01/2013 02:02pm
125485358802,WRONG_PERFORMANCE,g4t2,19/01/2013 02:02pm
172485359309,DAY_LIMIT_EXCEEDED,obelisk,19/01/2013 02:03pm
125485358802,DAY_LIMIT_EXCEEDED,obelisk,19/01/2013 02:03pm
```

What I need to do is get the total of each type of error and the location so for the first would be error: 'OBSOLETE_ORDER' and location: 'obelisk'.  I have tried to do this a number of ways but the best I can come up with is a multi dimensional array:

```
$error_handle = fopen("$reportUrl", "r");
while (!feof($error_handle) )
   {
      $line_of_text = fgetcsv($error_handle, 1024);
      $errorName = $line_of_text[1];
      $scannerName = $line_of_text[2];
      if($errorName != "SCAN_RESULT" && $errorName != "" && $scannerName != "SCAN_LOGIN" && $scannerName != "")
          {
              $errorsArray["$errorName"]["$scannerName"]++;
          }
   }
fclose($error_handle);
print_r($errorsArray);
```

gives me the following:

```
Array ( [OBSOLETE_ORDER] => Array ( [obelisk] => 1 ) [WRONG_PERFORMANCE] => Array ( [g3t1] => 2 [g4t1] => 2 [g4t2] => 2 ) [DAY_LIMIT_EXCEEDED] => Array ( [obelisk] => 2 ) )
```

which is great...except how do I then take that apart to add to my sql database?! (I am interested in getting the key and total of that key under the key the array is under)

and then add it to the tables

-errors-
(index)id_errors
id_event
id_access_scanner
id_errors_type
total_errors

-errors_type-
(index)id_errors_type
name_errors_type

-access_scanner-
(index)id_access_scanner
id_portal
name_access_scanner

PLEASE HELP!

Thanks!

Comment: what does `$line_of_text` contain? post code how you define it, pls

Answer (score 0):

A multidimensional array is more than you need. The approach to take is to create your own string (`$arrayKey` in my example) to use as an array key that combines the scanner name and the error so that you can get a count.

```
//this is the array containing all the report lines, each as an array
$lines_of_text;

//this is going to be our output array
$errorScannerArray = array();

//this variable holds the array key that we're going to generate from each line
$arrayKey = null;

foreach($lines_of_text as $line_of_text)
{
    //the array key is a combination of the scanner name and the error name
    //the tilde is included to attempt to prevent possible (rare) collisions
    $arrayKey = trim($line_of_text[1]).'~'.trim($line_of_text[2]);

    //if the array key exists, increase the count by 1
    //if it doesn't exist, set the count to 1
    if(array_key_exists($arrayKey, $errorScannerArray))
    {
        $errorScannerArray[$arrayKey]++;
    }
    else
    {
        $errorScannerArray[$arrayKey] = 1;
    }
}

//clean up
unset($line_of_text);
unset($arrayKey);
unset($lines_of_text);

//displaying the result
foreach($errorScannerArray as $errorScanner => $count)
{
    //we can explode the string hash to get the separate error and scanner names
    $names = explode('~', $errorScanner);
    $errorName = $names[0];
    $scannerName = $names[1];

    echo 'Scanner '.$scannerName.' experienced error '.$errorName.' '.$count.' times'."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With your edited question, this much simpler loop will work for you, you just need to then insert the data into your database inside the loop, instead of echoing it out:

```
$errorsArray = Array (
        [OBSOLETE_ORDER] => Array (
                                    [obelisk] => 1 
                                )
        [WRONG_PERFORMANCE] => Array (
                                    [g3t1] => 2 
                                    [g4t1] => 2 
                                    [g4t2] => 2 
                                ) 
        [DAY_LIMIT_EXCEEDED] => Array ( 
                                    [obelisk] => 2 
                                ) 
    )

foreach($errorsArray as $row => $errors) {
    foreach($errors as $error => $count) {
        echo $row;  // 'OBSOLETE_ORDER'
        echo $error;    // 'obelisk'
        echo $count;    // 1
        // insert into database here
    }
}
```

---

OLD ANSWER
You just need a new array to hold the information you need, ideally a count.
Im assuming that the correct data format is:

```
$report = [
  ['157479877294','OBSOLETE_ORDER','obelisk','19/01/2013 01:42pm'],
  ['191532426695','WRONG_PERFORMANCE','g3t1','19/01/2013 01:56pm'],
  ['159523681637','WRONG_PERFORMANCE','g3t1','19/01/2013 01:57pm'],
  ['176481653889','WRONG_PERFORMANCE','g4t1','19/01/2013 01:57pm'],
  .....
];

foreach($report as $array) {
  $errorName = $array[1];
  $scannerName = $array[2];
  if(exists($errorsArray[$errorName][$scannerName])) {
    $errorsArray[$errorName][$scannerName] = $errorsArray[$errorName][$scannerName] + 1;
  }
  else {
    $errorsArray[$errorName][$scannerName] = 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: your database field names dont mean much to me, what tables do these fields go into? What table does $errorName go into and what table does $scannerName go to?

Answer (score 0):

```
$list = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $values = explode(',' $line);
    $error = $values[1];
    $scanner = $values[2];
    if (!isset($list[$error])) {
         $list[$error] = array();
    }
    if (!isset($list[$error][$scanner])) {
         $list[$error][$scanner] = 1;
    } else {
         $list[$error][$scanner]++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To go through each result I just did the following:

```
foreach ($errorsArray as $errorName=>$info)
    {
        foreach ($info as $scannerName=>$total)
            {
                print "$errorName -> $scannerName = $total </br>";
            }
    }
```

and now will just connect it to the sql